# Checking if a relation is complete

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, algorithms

I have a transitive relation $\subset$ on a (finite and small) set S and a list of pairs $x_i\subset y_i.$ I would like to check if my list is complete in the sense that if $x\subset y$ then there are appropriate indices $i,j,\ldots,k$ such that
$$x=x_i\subset y_i=x_j\subset y_j=\cdots=x_k\subset y_k=y.$$

To do this I will need to prove assertions of the form $x\not\subset y$ for many pairs $(x,y).$ Since this is hard (each one is a proof!) I'd like to do the least number possible. I'm looking for an algorithm to give such a minimal list (which should be unique).

My initial idea:

1. With a new element $\top$, add $s\subset\top$ to the list for all $s\in S$.
2. Take the transitive reduction of the list (if $a\subset b$ and $b\subset c$ are on the list, remove $a\subset c$ from the list).
3. For each element $y\in S\cup\{\top\}$ find all $x_i$ such that $x_i\subset y$ is on the list.
4. For each pair $i\ne j$ check that $x_i\not\subset x_j$.

**The question:** Does my algorithm work? That is, does it generate the (1) enough pairs to check such that, if all noninclusions are verified, the (original) list is complete, and (2) no smaller set of pairs could be checked to reach the first conclusion?

Bonus: Give a better algorithm (a correct one if mine is wrong, or a simpler/faster one if mine is right).

Comment: I don't understand your definition of "completeness". When $x \subset y$, why couldn't you just take $x_1 = x$, $y_1 = y$, and say $x = x_1 \subset y_1 = y$? I also don't understand why proving completeness would entail proving assertions of the form $x \not\subset y$. Is there some typo in the definition?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo: You're ignoring the critical word "list". $x\subset y$ but I want to find, say, $x_1\subset x_2\subset x_3$ where "$x_1\subset x_2$" and "$x_2\subset x_3$" appear on the list. If you can always find such $x_i$ then the list is complete. If you can't then there's something the list is missing.

Comment: For example: My list might say (1) "a completely multiplicative sequence is multiplicative", (2) "a geometric sequence is a divisibility sequence"m, and (3) "a constant sequence is geometric". But in fact a completely multiplicative sequence is also a divisibility sequence, so my list is not complete because this cannot be derived from (1), (2), and (3). Also a constant sequence is a divisibility sequence, but this fact is represented in my list, it just takes two steps.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that the $\subset$ in "when $x \subset y$" was identical with the $\subset$ given by the list of pairs. On closer inspection I see that there is a distinction between the relation and the list of given pairs.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo: Yes. Apparently you were not the only one confused; if you have any suggestions for clarifying the wording I would appreciate them. I'd really like to solve this problem!

Comment: Your algorithm has someproblems with special cases. For example if $a\subset a$ then step 2 would remove $a\subset a$ from the list - but it is essential to keep it on the list

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I don't need $a\subset a$ though --  you can conclude that for any $a$.

Comment: I have noticed that you [have offered a bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1078925/revisions) but received no answer. Maybe you might be interested in my effort to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26). Feel free to ping me here or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room) after you see this message. (Since it is unrelated to the question, I prefer removing it after it served its purpose.)